# How to do negation for 'CONTAINS'

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I have Cassandra table with one column defined as set.
How can I achieve something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <set_column_name> NOT CONTAINS <value>
```

Proper secondary index in was already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html):

> SELECT select_expression   FROM keyspace_name.table_name   WHERE
>   relation AND relation ...    ORDER BY ( clustering_column ( ASC | DESC
>   )...)   LIMIT n   ALLOW FILTERING

then later:

> relation is:
>
> column_name op term

and finally:

> op is = | < | > | <= | > | = | CONTAINS | CONTAINS KEY

So there's no native way to perform such query. You have to workaround by designing a new table to specifically satisfy this query.